# Where can i find info.plist file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

I am reading an iOS dev book and in it saw a reference to a `info.plist` file used as part of an Obj-C project. Unfortunately, the book did not explicitly say where the file may be found?

Where is this file located? How can i gain access to it as part of Xcode?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `Info.plist` file is by default located in the root folder of your application's bundle, it's derived from the `{ProjectName}-Info.plist` file in the Xcode project. By default it's listed in a group called `Supporting Files`.

Comment: Yes. The Xcode editor supports the plist file format. If you click on it in Xcode the editor will display an editable table with all the keys and their associated type and value.

Comment: I just found {projectName}-info.plist in my project directory but editing it isn't working. Do i need to make the changes in Info.plist file also?

Comment: [About Information Property List Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html)

Answer (score 15):

The app I was developing had some custom settings and in my case the `Info.plist file` was in a different place.

Here is how I look for it. (the safest way)

In xCode:

- Click on the project (name)
- Click "Build Settings"
- Look for Packaging group
- Inside packaging group you will find your `Info.plist file`

In JetBrains AppCode:

- right click on project (name)
- click on "Project Settings"
- Select your Project in the above frame
- Look for "Info.plist File"

Answer (score 2):

**Info.plist location**

[[Info.plist]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61118898/4770877)

```
Build Settings -> Info.plist File(INFOPLIST_FILE)
```

When you create a new `Bundle`(Application, Framework, Tests), Xcode automatically save it into a place which you can find simply in `Build Settings`. But sometimes it is not so simple to find it, for example using `CocoaPods`

During refactoring or others situations the `Info.plist` path can be changed and Xcode do not automatically change `Build Settings` and you get

```
Build input file cannot be found: 'some_path/Info.plist' (in target 'SomeTarget' from project 'SomeProject')
```

You can fix it finding a file and modifying settings

```
File -> Open Quickly -> Find the correct one -> Reveal in Project Navigator -> update Info.plist File in the Build Settings
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using flutter the path is project-name\ios\Runner\Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

for those that like myself are building an Ionic project and have to add privacy permission keys, make sure you add them in the right `.plist` file. The best way to find it is to use Xcode search.
I share a screenshot with a circle around the right Info.plist you need to modify. Modifying the other one in the library folder will still result in errors about privacy. Hope this screenshot helps because I have lost a lot of time on this issue.
[image]