# How to get bundle ID?

Tags: ios, nsbundle

I am working on getting the facebook API working for iOS, and the FB registration page requires the Bundle ID of the project.  How can I get this information?  I read something about getting it at run time, but is there a way to get Xcode to tell me this information, or is it held in a plist somewhere.  I am not using the default bundle id, I remember setting it while I created the project.

Comment: The bundle ID should appear when you click on your project in Xcode and go to the 'info' tab.  It should look something like "com.mycompany.appname"

Answer (score 67):

If you are trying to get it programmatically , you can use below line of code :

objective C

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

Swift 3.0 :

```
let bundleIdentifier =  Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

It will work for both iOS and Mac apps 
Good luck..

Comment: this the solution I was looking for long time, thank you

Answer (score 36):

For those using Xcode >=7: select your target and click the *General* tab. *Bundle Identifier* is found under *Identity*.

Comment: what is the general tab ?

Comment: @romainjouin "...choose View > Navigators > Show Project Navigator. Choose the target from the Project/Targets pop-up menu or in the Targets section of the second sidebar if it appears. Click General..." from [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html)

Answer (score 17):

### Details

- Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500), Swift 5.1

### Programmatically

### Solution 1

```
let bundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

### Solution 2

```
let bundleId = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String
```

---

### From Xcode

### Solution 1

[image]

### Solution 2

[image]

Answer (score 15):

In Xcode 4, select your project, then your target (you should have only one) and then the 'Info' tab. You should be able to see the bundle identifier there.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is I am building a library, and when I click on the target, I only have "Build Settings" "Build Phases" and "Build Rules".  Is there another way to get this?

Comment: when it says PRODUCT_NAME do you have to replace that ?

Answer (score 5):

**iOS Bundle ID(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)**

A `bundle ID` or bundle identifier identifies an application in Apple's ecosystem. Apple advice to use reverse domain name(reverse DNS notation) to create it.

For example:

```
com.companyname
```

Bundle identifier is a string in `Info.plist`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61118898/4770877) which is required for any `Bundle`

To **set** it using Xcode

```
//Info.plist
Bundle identifier
//by default it points on `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` which is you can setup in Build Settings

//Build Settings the mirror of Target Settings
Build Settings -> Product Bundle Identifier(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)

//Target Settings the mirror of Build Settings
General -> Bundle Identifier
```

When you setup a new target you find

```
Bundle Identifier = Organization Identifier + ProductName
```

`Organization Identifier` is not take into account by Build Settings

[[ProductName]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57517400/4770877)

To **get** it programmatically

```
//Objective-C
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

//Swift
Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

[[Vocabulary]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)

Answer (score 2):

You can find out and change from supporting file=> info.plist => Bundle identifier

It is generally DNS form ex. com.companyname.appname

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're build a library, this may be problematic - it's applications that have a bundle ID. However, your can probably query this programatically using `[NSBundle mainBundle]` and then `[NSBundle bundleIdentifier]`