# How to add properties in info.plist in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, info.plist

I want to open PDF attachment via email in my own application: I refer two link here:

[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

and [here on Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app)

where it shows some XML content, and says its added to info.plist.My info.plist is shown like this attachment. How can I add content to info.plist to make it visible as XML document.

My info.plist:

[image]

Answer (score 26):

plist files is nothing more than XML document that Xcode view in his own way.
You can **Right click -> Open as -> Source Code** to get view you want.

Also you can add to plist directly by clicking plus sign or Right click -> Add Row.
Default view of plist can give you a suggestions, so I recommend you to use this instead of viewing as XML

Comment: The second option - right click - this works in Xcode 6.

Comment: this is a much cleaner option than the table view list format it is by default

Answer (score 16):

Info.plist is a system level plist in iPhone application, you can add properties by adding a property like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the .plist in Xcode and select "Open As -> Source code"

Answer (score 7):

may be worth mentioning how to get there..

Info.plist is one of the file below the Main.storyboard or viewController.swift

when you click on it first time it usually is in a table format,so right click the file and 'open as' Source code and then add the code

Answer (score 2):

If you want to view it as XML, just find the plist file and open it with your favorite editor. Something like TextWrangler. And then add your key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit info.plist**

To review properties in `info.plist`

- Open as -> Source Code
- `Version editor`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**XCODE 13**

You do not see your `info.plist` file in project folder until you try to modify it for the first time (lets say by adding value) in **target -> Info** - example seen on below:

[image: this picture] .

After you add any value in targets, the `info.plist` will be created and available for you somewhere in your project folder (example below)

[image: see this picture]

Comment: in the case of using XML, is the value where the XML goes?

Comment: @Joe IN case ox XML you need to right-click on "Info" and select "Open with external editor"

Comment: I never would have found that