# Does Google AdMob Require Info.plist exactly?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, admob

I am trying to set up Google AdMobs on a project that I have already set Firebase up in. I have been trying to follow the Update your info.plist section of the AdMob documentation here: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#swift

but I keep getting the "reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID. Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions at https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to set a valid application ID. Google Ad Manager publishers, follow instructions at [https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist."](https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist.%22) Error.

I am wondering if it is because my plist is named GoogleService-Info.plist rather than Info.plist (This is the name given by default when I first began using Firebase). If I try to rename the file to just Info.plist, the firestore part of my project breaks. Does AdMob require Info.plist to be named exactly that?

Answer (score 1):

I found that it does matter what plist I add Google AdMob to. XCode 13 got rid of the Info.plist but you can manually create an info.plist by following this guide: https://betterprogramming.pub/info-plist-is-missing-in-xcode-13-heres-how-to-get-it-back-1a7abf3e2514

Pasting to info.plist solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to dig more about `Info.plist`. See [this official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [this medium blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756636/what-is-the-use-of-plist).

First, `Info.plist` and `GoogleService-Info.plist` are used for different purposes. If you rename those files some of the service will break surely.

Second, Even if **XCode 13**, there is `Info.plist`(though you can't see in project navigator for fresh project). See [this medium blog](https://medium.com/@alessandromanilii/info-plist-in-xcode-13-791f02740235) how to configure Info.plist for **XCode 13**